# Getting Error with qoutes in MySQL query

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache

**Here is my code:**

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO clients (client_id, name, surname, tel1,tel2,id_num,address)
   VALUES ('" .$updating_id . "','" .$updatedName1 . "','" .$updatedName1 . "',  '" .$updatedSurname1
   . "', '" . $updatedTel1  . "', '" .$updatedTel2 . ", '" .$updatedId_num1. "', '" .$updatedAddress1.
   ")  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    name='" . $updatedName1 . "', surname='" . $updatedSurname1 . "',
   tel1='" . $updatedTel1 . "', tel2='" . $updatedTel2 . "', id_num='" . $updatedId_num1 . "',
   address='" .$updatedAddress1 . "'");
   if(mysql_query($result))
   {  echo $updatedName1,"  ", $updatedSurname1, " updated successfully "; 
   }                        
   else {
   echo  mysql_error();} 
   }
```

I am noticing that the first quote on the `mysql_query("INSERT INTO`...
is closing with the first quote of the `VALUES ('" .$updating_id . "'`... statement and yet the way I quoted is the one in my examples, I have assessed.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Do not longer use the deprecated `mysql_*` API. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statements.

Comment: @kristian the error is '
Query was empty '

Comment: You are calling `mysql_query` twice and calling it on `$result` makes no sense.

Comment: use `if($result)` instead of `if(mysql_query($result))`

Comment: @Vinie and GhostGambler thanks guys but now im getting the following arror: 
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in C:\xampplite\htdocs\leads\display_row.php on line 119  any suggestions

Comment: You are missing a closing single quote for the values $updatedTel2 and $updatedAddress1

Comment: If you are facing more problem then please echo your query ans execute it in phpmyadmin then see your query is right or not

Answer (score 2):

Use `if($result)` instead of `if(mysql_query($result))`. thx @Vinie

**And you miss two simple quotes in your `VALUES` statement:**

```
$updatedTel2 . "'
$updatedAddress1."'
```

And you need to have a look at `mysql_real_escape_string();` or at least use PDO :)

Comment: thanx  a lot this mysql_real_escape_string(); function saves onea lot of headaches